# SQL Query: Adding Percentage

Tags: mysql

I have a query that works but in addition to what I already have I want to add one extra column for each category free,reduced,paid and certified free with the percentage compared to the total number of students. Can anyone help me?

```
select
        count(case when Lunchstatus = 'P'   then 1 else null end) as Paid
      , count(case when LunchStatus = 'R'   then 1 else null end) as Reduced
      , count(case when LunchStatus = 'F'   then 1 else null end) as Free
      , count(case when LunchStatus = 'fdc' then 1 else null end) as CertifiedFree
      , count(case when LunchStatus = 'P'   then 1 
                   when LunchStatus = 'fdc' then 1 
                   when LunchStatus = 'R'   then 1 
                   when LunchStatus = 'F'   then 1 
                   else null 
                   end) as Total
    from students
    where enroll_status = 0 
      and schoolid = %param1%
```

Comment: extra column for each category free,reduced,paid what do you want to achive.. try to add more data

Comment: SHow output you get, then show output you want

Answer (score 0):

Treat you existing query as a derived table, cross join for the total count, then calculate your percentages:

```
select
       d.*
     , d.Paid * 100.0 / cj.totcount as paid_pct

     ... more like that

from (
      select
              count(case when Lunchstatus = 'P'   then 1 else null end) as Paid
            , count(case when LunchStatus = 'R'   then 1 else null end) as Reduced
            , count(case when LunchStatus = 'F'   then 1 else null end) as Free
            , count(case when LunchStatus = 'fdc' then 1 else null end) as CertifiedFree
            , count(case when LunchStatus = 'P'   then 1 
                         when LunchStatus = 'fdc' then 1 
                         when LunchStatus = 'R'   then 1 
                         when LunchStatus = 'F'   then 1 
                         else null 
                         end) as Total
      from students
      where enroll_status = 0 
      and schoolid = %param1%
      ) d
CROSS JOIN (
       select count(*) as totcount
       from students
       where enroll_status = 0 
       and schoolid = %param1%
       ) cj
```